# Array Mutation whilst being Enumerated

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsexception, mutation

so my issue is happening only when I have two enemies on a team in my game. If it's a one versus one.. I do not get the issue.

Please look at my code and see if you can gather as to why I'm getting this fatal error.

**Removes Target from players target array**

```
-(void)removeTarget:(PlayerClass *)target withSender:(PlayerClass *)sender {
    if ([sender.targets containsObject:target]) {
        [sender.targets removeObject:target];
    }
}
```

**Adds Target to players target array**

```
-(void)addTarget:(PlayerClass *)target withSender:(PlayerClass *)sender {

    //check if target already exists

    if ([sender.targets count] > 0) {
        for (PlayerClass *players in sender.targets) {
            if ([players.name isEqualToString:target.name]) {
                //Checked if exists, if target exists in list then move on.
                goto outer;
            }
        }
    }

    [sender.targets addObject:target];

    outer:;
}
```

**In the Update to determine whether they're a target or not**

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
/* Called before each frame is rendered */

for (PlayerClass *player in _players) {
    ....

    if (player.health > 0) { //If player is alive!

       ....
        //Checks if the player has targets, if so & visible - Engage.
        if ([player.targets count] > 0) {
            for (PlayerClass *enemy in player.targets) {
                if (![player.team isEqualToString:enemy.team]) {
                    if (enemy.health > 0) {
                        if ([self lineOfSightBetweenPlayers:player andPlayer:enemy]) {
                            [self attackWithPlayer:player againstPlayer:enemy];
                            break;
                        } else {
                            [player removeTarget:enemy withSender:player];
                        }
                    } else {
                        [player removeTarget:enemy withSender:player];
                    }
                } else {
                    [player removeTarget:enemy withSender:player];
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Now from debugging I've gathered that the players don't add their team mates as targets. However, the player will gather more than one target if they can see more than one target on the opposing team. However, the issue I'm guessing lies in my technique to removing a target from the array? Can anyone check over and make sure I'm not delivering a school boy error here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple fix. Wasn't thinking outside the box.. which tends to happen when code starts getting very large!

```
        //Checks if the player has targets, if so & visible - Engage.
        if ([player.targets count] > 0) {
            for (PlayerClass *enemy in player.targets) {
                if (![player.team isEqualToString:enemy.team]) {
                    if (enemy.health > 0) {
                        if ([self lineOfSightBetweenPlayers:player andPlayer:enemy]) {
                            [self attackWithPlayer:player againstPlayer:enemy];
                            break;
                        } else {
                            [player removeTarget:enemy withSender:player];
                            break;
                        }
                    } else {
                        [player removeTarget:enemy withSender:player];
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    [player removeTarget:enemy withSender:player];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Fixed my issue, I wasn't breaking out. Thus enumerating after removal.